# Clear field value and simulate enter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the quicksearch (https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch) jQuery to hide elements in a `table` by entering text into a text box and then it only shows the ones that match.

This works fine, but I want to be able to clear the text box. I am using the following code to do that...

```
<script>
function clearsearch(){  
document.getElementById('id_search').value = "";
}
</script>

<a onclick="clearsearch()" id="clearsearch">Clear</a>
```

This also works fine at clearing the field, but the script doesn't respond. I think the reason why it's not responding is because when I clear it with the clear script above, **I need to focus on the `input` and press the delete key.**

Ex.) If I simply type text in the text box, and then delete it by hand, it works fine. If I run the clear script, and it deletes the text, the results don't show. If I run the script, it deletes the text, and I press delete within the `input` the script responds.

Is there a way that I can first clear the text box, and then simulate the delete key within the text box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems quicksearch is bound to the keyup event [by default](https://github.com/riklomas/quicksearch/blob/master/jquery.quicksearch.js#L10).  Try triggering that.

```
$('#id_search').trigger('keyup');
```

You can also use jQuery to set the value:

```
$('#id_search').val('').trigger('keyup');
```

Comment: Perfect, how does it do that though when it seems to work with the delete key?

Comment: @Charlie: When you press the delete key (or any other key) in the field, it's triggering the `keyup` event.  So, triggering it programmatically should work too.

Comment: Oh my sweet jesus, that was what I've been trying to do for the last 2 hours.

Comment: @FreshPro: I'm glad my post from 2 years ago was able to help you! :-D

Comment: You bet it helped! Cheers mate